# Set different background color in datagridrow bound based on datatablerow state

Tags: c#, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I am fetching data from database using dataset and binding it to datagrid at run time.

```
EventGrid.ItemsSource = Events.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Based on the row state of rows in Events.Tables[0], i want to display a backgroud colour in datagrid.

Colour Code-

```
             **RowState**       **BackgroundColor**
               Added                  Red
              Unchaged               Green
               Edited                Yellow
```

How do i achieve this using xaml/c#

Answer (score 1):

You can bind datagrid property to one property in model, that read data from Events.Tables[0], and add a converter class to convert Rowstate to BackgroundColor.

Also you can use Telerik, may help you to do this.